# Prolog - check the end of the stream doesn't work

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, iso-prolog

I have a file `memo.dat` , with these terms:

```
memo(verdi,11).
memo(rossi,7).
memo(bianchi,9).
memo(blu,7).
memo(neri,11).
memo(carli,11).
memo(rapini,8).
```

I wrote a prolog program in order to obtain a set of tuples from this file:

```
memo_to_list(MemoList):-
    open('/home/ale/Downloads/Prolog_exercises/memo.dat',read,Stream),
    read_list_from_stream(Stream,MemoList),
    close(Stream).

read_list_from_stream(Stream,[]):-
    at_end_of_stream(Stream),!.

read_list_from_stream(Stream,[(Cognome,Ora)|RestoAppuntamenti]):-
    read(Stream,memo(Cognome,Ora)),
    read_list_from_stream(Stream,RestoAppuntamenti).
```

However, the predicate `at_end_of_stream` fails to check when the stream reaches its end. What can be the problem ? (I used the ubuntu default text editor to create the file `memo.dat`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end of the stream is only detected when you actually reach it. When you read the last fact, the end-of-file marker have yet to be read. Try instead something like:

```
memo_to_list(MemoList):-
    open('/home/ale/Downloads/Prolog_exercises/memo.dat',read,Stream),
    read(Stream,Term),
    read_list_from_stream(Term,Stream,MemoList),
    close(Stream).

read_list_from_stream(end_of_file,_,[]) :-
    !.

read_list_from_stream(memo(Cognome,Ora),Stream,[(Cognome,Ora)|RestoAppuntamenti]):-
    read(Stream,Term),
    read_list_from_stream(Term,Stream,RestoAppuntamenti).
```

You can also avoid leaking stream handles and unclosed streams in case something is wrong with your data file by using the `setup_call_cleanup/3` built-in predicate:

```
memo_to_list(MemoList) :-
    setup_call_cleanup(
        open('/Users/pmoura/Desktop/memo.dat',read,Stream),
        (   read(Stream,Term),
            read_list_from_stream(Term,Stream,MemoList)
        ),
        close(Stream)
    ).
```

**Update**

The Prolog standard requires that the `.` that ends a term is followed by a layout character. Your code only works if there isn't any character (other than the end-of-file) after the last dot of the last term, which makes the Prolog text non-conforming but, depending on the Prolog system, may allow the end of stream to be detected by calling the `at_end_of_stream /1` predicate after reading the last term. Note also that's common for text editors to add a new-line after the last line of text if not present on saving. That new-line is a layout character as required by the Prolog standard. Therefore, for a compliant, reliable, and portable solution, make sure there's a new line at the end of your data file and use a solution along this answer.

Comment: Thanks so much. Anyway also my code should work. Maybe it's a problem in the text editor. The program i wrote it's a standard one so it should work...

Comment: Updated my answer with an extended explanation.

Comment: Thanks i changed editor (Notepadqq) and now it works :)

Comment: Do you think that this behaviour of `at_end_of_steam/1` is conforming? Shouldn't it rather check if there is more to read? SWI did this, some time ago.